Notes not in key
I've noticed that my song has a whole bunch of notes that aren't all together in any key but I don't know, as it sounds good to me. I can't hear any flats or anything. Is there a reason it would sound ok?
The notes are as follows. I'm not sure if the flats are sharps or visa versa.
A A# C D D# F F# G

It is really OK and exciting that you are naturally moving to to compose atonal (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atonality) or maybe you are even thinking about microtonal (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microtone_(music)) music. Of course, then there is noise music as well. If you are having fun with atonal and microtonal expressions then this is really cool!

OK, but I wanted to add warning as well - atonal, microtonal music can be failure from the commercial point of view, most likely, sadly. So, caution is advised.

There is no rule whatsoever stating that notes must belong to a particular key. I would love to know how this myth is getting perpetuated! Perhaps it's for beginners, to keep them on the straight and narrow!
Re-ordering the notes into what's nearly a diatonic set gives B♭, C, D, E♭ F, F♯/G♭, G, A. Pretty close to B♭ major, with that exception of F♯/G♭. Or better still (thanks elements in space) Gm. It would be helpful if we knew what the 'home', root, or tonic note would be - that could establish a better answer.
However, all 12 notes, both the 7 diatonic, and the remaining 5 chromatics, can be and often are, used in songs. No reason not to. Using notes 'out of key' will add colour to any melody - in the appropriate places - which is often where they show themselves. Another place is where there's a modulation, or a key change. Yet another is as passing notes - so F>F♯>G could well be that scenario.

I bet it’s G minor.

@ElementsInSpace - you've won the bet!!

"There is no rule whatsoever stating that notes must belong to a particular key." So far, the only place where I ran into someone believing this sort of thing is here at Music SE. I really hope it isn't going to spread!

@Divizna - it does seem to be epidemic for questions on this site. I've always said 'use any of the twelve notes available - once you know what you're doing...'

@Tim I'm not even sure if you need to know what you're doing... I didn't have the slightest clue what I was doing when I composed my oldest tune sometime at 9yo or so. (Just the melody, four phrases total, nothing big, but IMO nice.) Turns out it's firmly in F# major (no notes out of key), but I didn't know that for years to come, I was just playing with the black keys because our teacher said that "Chinese music uses those, it's called pentatonic" - notably not a peep about where the tonic should be. Can't vouch for the cluelessness of my intuition, but on conscious level - not a faintest.

@Divizna - true, I've played with many good musos who 'don't know what they're doing', but still great players. But it's always better to break 'the rules' if you actually know what they are!

@Tim At least there is a difference between willfully breaking rules because you know what you’re doing and breaking rules by accident because you do not know what you are doing. Because theory is there not to restrict you, but to help you. And at some point you might break a rule you are not aware of by accident, and wonder, why your music does not sound 100% right. Then the theory might tell you the reason. Maybe don’t call it rules, call it guidelines ...

@Divizna maybe we've been wrong all along, and we've been performing and listening to the music of composers who didn't know what they were doing!!

@phoog - this opens up a whole can of worms : did all composers actually know what they were doing? Example - Beatles..?

@phoog I never said you shouldn't know what you're doing. I said I don't think it's strictly necessary. I'd argue, though, that simply not knowing is better than being sure about something that's in fact wrong.

@Divizna - true enough. Over many decades, I've had arguments with folk who think they know what they're doing - but, alas... Sometimes, you just have to smile and agree!

If you like the sound of the song as it is, then that is the way the song is. But some flats instead of sharps probably would make sense.
This is your row of notes:
A A♯ C D D♯ F F♯ G
Note that not all of the seven note names, A, B, C, D, E, F and G are present either as naturals or as accidentals.
I think it would make sense to have a row where they are all present like this row:
A B♭ C D E♭ F F♯ G
That is all I can say without seing the actual sheet music.


I'm not sure if the flats are sharps or visa versa.

The clue that the "black" notes are flats in this case is that you have two kinds of A (A and A♯) but no kind of B.  If you change the A♯ to B♭ then you have one kind of A and one kind of B.  The same logic applies to D and D♯ (which should in fact be E♭).
The F and F♯ have a different explanation, which is that the note below the tonic in minor keys is "naturally" a whole step below, but it is usually raised by chromatic alteration when there is a cadence on the tonic, so you will find both pitches in most minor-key music.  The fact that you have both F and F♯ is consistent with the hypothesis that this piece is in G minor.

(Of course, "diagnosing" the accidentals is impossible if they're not actually scale members. The whole thing could be in C, or anything else, and just have a lot of chromaticism! See my favorite Christmas example, though I'm sure we could find numbers with even more...)

@AndyBonner in fact, accidentals do tend to have fairly well defined roles in common practice tonal music; as you know well, both ^6 and ^7 can be major or minor in a minor key, and in major keys you'll usually find ^4 raised as a secondary leading tone to the dominant (for example, every now and again someone asks here if Star Spangled Banner is in Lydian mode).  Obviously it's not generally possible to identify a piece's key by just looking at the set of pitches, but as Elements in Space shows it is possible in many cases.  The more chromatic the piece, the more context matters.

We can't actually tell much just by knowing the notes that are used. Most music is in a key, and most of that music is either major or minor. (Some music is in no key, and some is in other "modes"!) But also, most music doesn't follow a rule that it can use only the notes in the key. (Sometimes composers or styles might impose special strict rules on themselves, like when learning "counterpoint" as a composition exercise, but that doesn't describe most of the music that's made and listened to.)
Consider the Christmas song "It's Beginning to Look a Lot Like Christmas", in the key of C major:*

We have F#, G#, A#, Ab, and D#, and there are more like these in the rest of the song. Being "in the key of C major" isn't determined by which notes you use—well, I mean, they help—but mostly by what you do with them. Where the melody leads to, where it rests, how it implies chords that go along with it.
All these flats and sharps ("accidentals") have reasons for being there. If we interrogate them and ask them to explain themselves, different ones will have different alibis. That first F# says "I'm just the lower neighbor of the Gs that are on either side of me, and I'm just staying close to them." The D# at the end of the excerpt says "Well, although you started in C, we're about to tonicize A minor briefly, so the next chord is the dominant of A, which is E, and I'm here as its leading tone."
So to figure out why the collection of notes you provided "sounds good," you'd have to do a harmonic analysis of what's going on. (In fact, even to know the key for sure you'd have to do the first steps of one!)
* If you're concerned about the eighth note rhythms, never mind; the point here is just the pitches. I've seen notations with dotted 8ths, with lots of triplets, and with 8ths intended to be "swung" in a triplet ratio, and being lazy, I went with the latter. I didn't try to find out what was used in the most original version. 

My answer just presents the info already in the other answers, but in a "process order" that might help people beginning to learn about keys and key signatures.
The OP's tones are:
A A♯ C D D♯ F F♯ G
I assume we are working with music that is more or less the major/minor system of keys, tonal music. We want a set of tones which uses each of the seven pitch letters only once, A B C D E F G, Notice that some letters are used twice - A, D, and F - and some are "missing" - B and E.
Re-spell the OP's tones with sharps (or if they used flats) to their enharmonic equivalent which will supply the "missing letters":

A# = Bb
D# = Eb
F# = Gb

Notice that the F# respelled to enharmonic equivalent Gb creates another duplicate. This presents a bit of a conundrum vis a vis seven letters each used only once. For the moment let's list that one tone as F#/Gb. With the enharmonic replacements we get:
A Bb C D Eb F F#/Gb G
Is there a key signature that uses Bb and Eb, and logically the F# would not be in a key signature of flats, so we tentatively include the Gb.
There is no key signature with Bb, Eb, and Gb, but there is one with two flats of Bb and Eb, namely Bb major or G minor.
We can reorder the tones for Bb major:
Bb C D Eb F F#/Gb G A
Or, we can reorder the tones for G minor:
G A Bb C D Eb F F#/Gb
Now we can approach the F#/Gb. There are a few  fairly common ways to explain that option.

F#/Gb could be a chromatic passing tone between the F and G
F# could be a chromatic auxiliary tone embellishing the G
if the music is in G minor F# would act as the leading tone to the tonic tone G

The first two bullet points would most likely be in a Bb major context to distinguish them from the F# leading tone in G minor.
So, finally we can say this set of tones is nominally in Bb major or G minor.
We would need to see the OP's actual music to say anything more definite, but the set of tones is not necessarily "not in a key."
